# How can I combine excel sheets

Tags: excel

I have an excel with different sheets and same formats. Is there any plugin available to combine all sheets into a "Merged" sheet? Any help is truly appreciated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use vba,

```
Sub Combine()
Dim J As Integer
On Error Resume Next
Sheets(1).Select
Worksheets.Add
Sheets(1).Name = "Merged"
Sheets(2).Activate
Range("A1").EntireRow.Select
Selection.Copy Destination:=Sheets(1).Range("A1")
For J = 2 To Sheets.Count
Sheets(J).Activate
Range("A1").Select
Selection.CurrentRegion.Select
Selection.Offset(1, 0).Resize(Selection.Rows.Count - 1).Select
Selection.Copy Destination:=Sheets(1).Range("A65536").End(xlUp)(2)
Next
End Sub
```